# "shape burst" stroke in iOS Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, stroke

Is there a way to create the following effect in Core Graphics by stroking a CGPathRef?

[image: IMG]

If it *is* possible, would it be more efficient to draw with Core Graphics vs. simply drawing a radial ellipse CGImageRef a whole bunch of times along the path?

Edit: to clarify: I want the central part of the stroke to be 100% opacity, and the edges to fade out from 100% opacity to 0% opacity.

Edit 2: also, I intend to use this drawing in an MKOverlayView to highlight a user's path... so not sure if a blur filter would be performant enough.

Comment: Have you experimented with setting a shadow whilst drawing the ellipse?

Comment: @fzwo It's possible, but I don't really see any blur support in Core Graphics. Could you let me know more about what you mean?

Comment: @jrturton I'll look into shadows now, but an ellipse won't work since the shape is actually a technically a rounded rect, and I'd want to concatenate a whole bunch of these together to stroke a path. But maybe a shadow on a stroked path...

Comment: @awolf Sorry, I wasn't really suggesting a blur, I was merely inquiring what the exact effect was you wanted to achieve. As @jrturton suggested, I'd try shadows (but I've never needed to do that in core graphics, so can't be of further help - but maybe `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` can help you achive what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A round-capped, thick path with a shadow on it is probably the best solution for you. That would involve:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth()
CGContextSetLineCap()
CGContextSetShadowWithColor()
```

You'd want a zero offset shadow, and you'll need to experiment with the radius and blur parameters to get the effect you're after.